# React setting multiple states dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im learning React and currently playing with passing data around.

I have info for 5 cards stored in state like this:

```
state = {
    cards: [
        { id: 1, name: "p1", value: "Prize 1", imageSrc: "/path/to/image", bgColor: { background: "#FF6384", border: "4px solid #FF6384" } },
        { id: 2, name: "p2", value: "Prize 2", imageSrc: "/path/to/image", bgColor: { background: "#4BC0C0", border: "4px solid #4BC0C0" } },
        { id: 3, name: "p3", value: "Prize 3", imageSrc: "/path/to/image", bgColor: { background: "#FFCE56", border: "4px solid #FFCE56" }},
        { id: 4, name: "p4", value: "Prize 4", imageSrc: "/path/to/image", bgColor: { background: "#67bd42", border: "4px solid #67bd42" } },
        { id: 5, name: "p5", value: "Prize 5", imageSrc: "/path/to/image", bgColor: { background: "#c931f7", border: "4px solid #c931f7" }}
    ],
    flipped: null,
   };
```

I am displaying them with an iteration, like this:

```
<div className="prize-cards-inner">
                {this.state.cards.map((card) => {
                    return (
                        <section key={card.id} className="prize-card-container">
                            <div
                                className={`prize-card ${
                                    this.state.flipped === card ? "flipped" : ""
                                    }`}
                                onClick={() => this.clickHandler(card)}
                            >
                                <div className="front">
                                    <div className="card-name-div" style={ card.bgColor }>
                                        {card.value}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="prize-image-div" >
                                        <img className="prize-image"  src={card.imageSrc} alt="test" /> 
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="slot-name-div" style={card.bgColor}>
                                       <p> {card.name}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="back">Prize</div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    );
                })}
                
            </div>
```

and handling card clicks with this:

```
    clickHandler = (card) => {
    if (this.state.flipped) {
        return;
    }
    this.setState({
        flipped: card,
        ***Set another state for all other cards (how do I say "set the state of all cards that aren't this card?")***
    });

};
```

I would like to set the state for all other cards aside from the clicked card at the same time I set the state for the clicked card.
I have no clue how to do what I want, so I have marked the part I am unsure about with asterisks. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: First of all, I don't understand the part `***Set another state for all other cards (how do I say "set the state of all cards that aren't this card?")***`. Explain the app logic, what are you trying to do? In the current situation your app is, you are controlling ALL the cards with the `flipped` state, not only individual card. Maybe you want to set the `flipped` to the each individual card.

Comment: as it currently is, the click only sets the state of the clicked card to flipped. Tried and tested. I want to set all other cards to a different state on the same click, however.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the `this.state.flipped === card` (mistook for `true/false`). But either way, you SHOULD add a *flipped* property to the *card* object itself, because as is, you are comparing *objects* x-times (where x: number of cards). Don't you think that comparing objects is slower than just having to compare booleans?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite understanding.
In the first set of code, I explicitly set all cards to a state of "null".  On click I just swap the property to "card" for the card that's clicked. The iteration through all the cards on click is to see if any are already flipped so all cards can be disabled, disallowing another click. Are you saying theres a way to do this with booleans in react? I'm not understanding the equating logic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```js
clickHandler(card) {
 if (this.state.flipped) {
   return;
 }

 this.setState((state) => ({
   flipped: card,
   cards: state.cards.map((c) => (
     // If the card we are mapping is not the flipped card add someOtherState to it 
     c === card ? c : { ...c, someOtherState: 'some value'};
   )),
 });
};
```

I'd recommend you start using functional components with React hooks right away. They provide a much nicer developer experience

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the logic I need. Unfortunately for me, it's throwing an unexpected token at the curly bracket before the ...c and I'm not smart enough to know why...
Will definitely be looking into functional components with hooks. thanks again

Comment: I forgot a colon in that ternary operator. The answer is updated and should work now. Mark as the best answer, please. Good luck!!

Comment: I would love to, but it's still throwing an error. I set up a codepen:
https://codepen.io/picktatar/pen/GRvPNRg?editors=0010

it errors with your extra code, works (card flipping) without it and no errors.

Comment: ahah. Yeah, writing code in the stackoverflow editor is a pain.
Here I forked your codepen: https://codepen.io/fundispenser/pen/OJjrvyO

Comment: Thank you Anton, this is almost exactly what I needed. It took me a second to suss how it worked, but I'm all good now! Again, much appreciated.